# SQL Não exibir linhas de uma coluna duplicada

Tags: sql, sql-server

Olá pessoal estou tendo dificuldade em não exibir os itens de uma coluna duplicada, no caso a coluna C.CLI_ID, preciso que mostre apenas o primeiro resultado. Já tentei de diversas maneiras porem SQL não é minha especialidade já estou sem ideias.

```
SELECT c.cli_id, C.cli_data_cadastro, CT.cont_id, CT.cont_data_vencimento, T.tituloid, T.dataven, T.datapag, T.valorpago, 

CASE 

WHEN T.valorpago <= '0' THEN 'Não Pago'

WHEN ct.cont_data_vencimento  > FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND T.valorpago > '0' THEN 'Pago'

WHEN ct.cont_data_vencimento < FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')  AND T.valorpago > '0' THEN 'Vencido'

END AS situacao 

FROM cliente_rbdigital AS C, contrato_rbdigital AS CT

INNER JOIN titulo_rbdigital AS T ON T.contratoid=CT.cont_id 

WHERE C.cli_id = CT.cont_cliente_id 

ORDER BY C.cli_data_cadastro DESC, situacao DESC


10472   2020-07-31 11:58:44 39486   2020-08-30  39409   2020-08-03  NULL    0.00    Não Pago
10471   2020-07-31 09:57:22 39484   2021-01-27  39407   2020-08-03  2020-07-31  119.40  Pago
10470   2020-07-31 09:35:45 39483   2020-10-29  39406   2020-08-03  NULL    0.00    Não Pago
10469   2020-07-31 05:39:23 39488   2021-01-27  39411   2020-08-01  2020-07-31  119.40  Pago
10469   2020-07-31 05:39:23 39478   2021-01-27  39401   2020-08-03  NULL    0.00    Não Pago
10468   2020-07-30 21:48:26 39473   2020-08-29  39396   2020-08-02  2020-07-30  19.90   Pago
10467   2020-07-30 21:48:21 39472   2021-01-26  39395   2020-08-02  NULL    0.00    Não Pago
10466   2020-07-30 19:54:12 39467   2020-08-29  39391   2020-08-02  2020-07-30  19.90   Pago
10465   2020-07-30 16:54:29 39463   2020-08-29  39386   2020-08-02  NULL    0.00    Não Pago
10464   2020-07-30 09:18:43 39458   2021-07-30  39381   2020-08-02  2020-07-30  238.80  Pago
10463   2020-07-30 07:59:46 39459   2020-08-29  39382   2020-07-31  2020-07-30  9.90    Pago
```

Comment: Você não quer que os resultados venham duplicados, correto?

Comment: Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808854/sql-server-equivalent-of-postgresql-distinct-on

Comment: E, no caso de linhas repetidas para um mesmo valor de cli_id, qual é o critério para definir qual linha será exibida e quais serão suprimidas?

Comment: O que você quer fazer, exatamente? Não está claro, porque as linhas não são duplicatas. São linhas legítimas e de acordo com o SQL que você montou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei exatamente o que você quer fazer com essa consulta, porque ela não está trazendo duplicatas e sim exatamente o que você digitou no SQL.

Se você quer que retornem somente os clientes que tenham *PELO MENOS* um contrato *E PELO MENOS* um título, veja abaixo:

```
SELECT C.cli_id, 
       C.cli_data_cadastro, 
       CT2.cont_id, 
       CT2.cont_data_vencimento, 
       T2.tituloid, 
       T2.dataven,
       T2.datapag, 
       T2.valorpago, 
       CASE
         WHEN T2.valorpago <= 0 THEN 'Não Pago'
         WHEN CT2.cont_data_vencimento > GETDATE() AND T2.valorpago > 0 THEN 'Pago'
         WHEN CT2.cont_data_vencimento < GETDATE() AND T2.valorpago > 0 THEN 'Vencido'
       END AS situacao

FROM cliente_rbdigital C

CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 CT.cont_id, CT.cont_data_vencimento
  FROM contrato_rbdigital CT
  WHERE CT.cont_cliente_id = C.cli_id
  ORDER BY CT.cont_data_vencimento
) CT2

CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 T.tituloid, T.dataven, T.datapag, T.valorpago
  FROM titulo_rbdigital T
  WHERE T.contratoid = CT2.cont_id
  ORDER BY T.valorpago
) T2

ORDER BY C.cli_data_cadastro DESC, situacao DESC
```

Veja também no db<>Fiddle, clicando [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6d4158950160ef2953850d40ae482759).

Comment: Alguns clientes tem mais de 1 contrato por isso a coluna CLI_ID aparece "duplicada", eu quero que elimine esses resultados e mostre somente o primeiro resultado.

Comment: Se a minha resposta resolveu o seu problema, favor marcar como melhor resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, acho que com sua resposta vou conseguir resolver o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Um `GROUP BY C.CLI_ID` resolveria a questão de não exibir mais de uma vez a linha de um mesmo cliente(eu acho).
Embora eu não sei se é uma boa ideia no seu caso

```
10469   2020-07-31 05:39:23 39488   2021-01-27  39411   2020-08-01  2020-07-31  119.40  Pago
10469   2020-07-31 05:39:23 39478   2021-01-27  39401   2020-08-03  NULL    0.00    Não Pago
```

O CT.Cont_id tem valores diferentes para as duas linhas e ao agrupá-los vai perder essa informação.

Comment: O `T.tituloid` também não é o mesmo... na verdade, nem sei o que o cara quer com essa consulta :/